# Development of High Performance Web Spider

Tags: php, c++, c, web-crawler

I'd like to develop a WebSpider daemon (PHP/C/C++)
Do you know a good reference about How to develop 
High Performance Web Crawler?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rcm/websphinx/) is an example library with source written in java. Also [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/become/) is an example of "large" crawler with schematics.